# Get actual line height in multiline TextField AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a multiline TextField that is 25 lines or so tall.  I need to be able to draw a line beneath certain pieces of the text.  I was trying to use TextLineMetrics to get the dimensions of the line heights, but it doesn't seem to be working properly.
Does anyone know of a solution for this?  I've seen FTE fonts mentioned some, but am not familiar with those.  Is that something to look into?
Thanks.

CODE:

```
textbox1.insidetext.text = currtext[0];
var metrics:TextLineMetrics = textbox1.insidetext.getLineMetrics(0);
lineHeight = metrics.ascent + metrics.descent;

// This is inside a function that gets called on a timer
if (readLine.x == textbox1.x) {
    readLine.x = (textbox1.width / 2) + textbox1.x;
} else {
    readLine.x = textbox1.x;
    readLine.y = readLine.y + lineHeight;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code that's not working?

Comment: @Cameron Updated above. :)

Comment: Nope, sorry. My Flash is getting rustier all the time -- the last time I had to measure text I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4628584/21475) but that's unlikely to apply here; TextLineMetrics looks like the way to go. Are you sure the initial line height is wrong? (Have you tried tracing it?)

Comment: That's cool, man.  Thanks for trying!
I've been tracing it out, but I really think it's just some sort of limitation on the multiline use of the TextField.  I'll play with it some more and maybe dynamically break the TextField up into multiple single-line TextFields.  There's more than one way to tackle this, they just all seem to be complicated.  I should know by now that Flash is just stupidly difficult sometimes. :)

Comment: I got it figured out.  I was resizing my TextField and that threw off my TextLineMetrics.  I got the original size of the TextField, made an adjustment ratio and multiplied my lineHeight by that ratio.  Everything worked perfectly after that.

Answer (score 3):

I got it figured out. I was resizing my TextField and that threw off my TextLineMetrics. I got the original size of the TextField, made an adjustment ratio and multiplied my lineHeight by that ratio. Everything worked perfectly after that.

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad you found the solution!